# Flutter: Disable Swipe to Navigate Back in iOS and Android

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm new to flutter development, and find it a bit frustrating in iOS when you have a navigation drawer and when you swipe to open it, it'll perform a `Navigation.of(context).pop()`. I would like to disable this "swipe to pop" behavior in iOS. I have been perusing the documentation, but without much luck.

I do see something referred to as a [`WillPopScope`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) which seems to do the trick ([github issue for it here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14203)), but I'm not 100% sure if this is the "correct" way to do it (it seems too complicated... it should be easier... like a setting on the root app).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I have one additional point here. I was just solving this problem, but I also needed my user to be able to go back by pressing the "native" back button on the AppBar (did not want to reimplement AppBar just because of this), and I found this niche little flag: `userGestureInProgress` on the Navigator object, so what I use (and presume is the preferred way) is:

```
onWillPop: () async {
    return !Navigator.of(context).userGestureInProgress;
},
```

Comment: Not working on Android. userGestureInProgress always returns false...

Comment: You can even simplify it this way:
`onWillPop: () async => !Navigator.of(context).userGestureInProgress`

Comment: @poqueque I have the same issue, it returns false only on Android. Opened an issue for Flutter about it, feel free to upvote https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/130401

Answer (score 73):

`WillPopScope` **is** the correct way to do this.

> (it seems too complicated... it should be easier... like a setting on the root app).

It is not complicated. It's a one liner :

```
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async => false,
  child: <children here>
)
```

A configuration file would make things more complicated as it's harder to read and maintain.

And remember that **in flutter everything is a widget** not just half of them. Authentification, configurations, everything.

Comment: hey @Darky are we becoming friends :P I actually found a neat way to do this... I am about to post my answer.

Comment: @rémi-rousselet: do you know why returning true instead of false also prevents from poping?

Comment: I simply changed "return false" to "return true", so that the hardware and appbar back buttons work while the swipe back is still disabled.

Comment: @Benjamin @Max wait what ? `return true` should be the equivalent of not canceling pops. The fact that it prevents IOS swipe is most likely a bug.

Comment: @RémiRousselet : you are most likely right. My question was rhetorical ;-)

Comment: is there a way to make use of ```WillPopScope``` while still keeping the default swipe back default IOS behaviour, i.e. to ```return true;```?

Comment: Does that also work on namedRoutes? Couldn't disable it with WillPopScope...

Comment: Big like for this. Thanks!

Comment: *** If you want the iOS swipe gesture to work, set onWillPop to null instead of a function. ***

Comment: Not working in the case of InAppWebView Implemented as a Child. How can we prevent it in InAppWebView? @RémiRousselet

Comment: On android, setting this to false is still showing the global swipe controls and capturing it before I can react in my widget. For example, I have a video scrubber bar that is the width of the page. If I start at 0 and try to scrub to the middle of the video, the app (or the phone?) thinks I'm trying to swipe and still shows the default "swipe from edge" controls and captures the gesture before my scrubber can react to it. If I set this to false, it doesn't navigate back but it still captures the swipe while just staying on the page (and not scrubbing).

Comment: ```WillPopScope``` is now deprecated. Use ```PopScope``` instead.

Answer (score 30):

`MaterialPageRoute` has a parameter called `fullscreenDialog` which is set to false by default. When true your page animates a bit differently and swipe to go back on iOS will be disabled.

Example usage:

```
 Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage(), fullscreenDialog: true));
```

See some discussion here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14203

Comment: This works for me perfectly for a terms and condition page. thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You can try this in your Widget build:

```java
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      //forbidden swipe from userGestureInProgress
      onWillPop: () async => !(Navigator.of(context).userGestureInProgress),
      child: <your child>,
    );
  }
```

Comment: onWillPop can be shorted like this `onWillPop: () async => !(Navigator.of(context).userGestureInProgress),`

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to block the swipe to return back in navigation (default pop function). This code helped fix the problem.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Example'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This code now blocks the back navigation for iOS & Android (default back button) and that's exactly what I was looking for. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Update for new Flutter version : WillPopScope is now became PopScope with a easier canPop properties

```
PopScope(
  canPop : false,
  child : --child here--
)
```

This code should do the trick

Answer (score 4):

Whenever the **back button** or **Swipe gesture(iOS)** is pressed, you will get a callback at `onWillPop`,
which returns a `Future`. If the `Future` returns true, the screen is popped(i.e navigate to the previous screen), If it is false, then it doesn't navigate back.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        return Future.value(false);
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Second Screen"),),
        body: Center(
```

And if you want to pop screen on a condition basis then declare

```
bool shouldPop = true; // change this using setState() inside build on the requirement. 

  onWillPop: () {
        return Future.value(shouldPop? true: false);
      },
```

Answer (score 3):

Alright, so as @Darky said `WillPopScope` is a perfectly acceptable answer, however, if you want to disable it across the board you can actually do the following.

Open your project in xcode, find `AppDelegate.swift` and add the following:

```
let controller: FlutterViewController
    = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController;
controller.navigationController?
    .interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Uh ! I find this horrible tbh. You should never touch ios/android folders and only code in dart. If you really wanted to disable it everywhere, then it should be written in dart and passed to `MaterialApp` or `WidgetApp`.

Comment: Oh I agree, there should be a setting or property that can be simply passed into the root of your `MaterialApp` but alas there isn't. :'(

Comment: Modify flutter's source. You don't even need to leave your IDE.  You can place breakpoints, edit, and hot-reload flutter sources too. Without even leaving your app.

Comment: Your fix would basically be to wrap **everything** in a `WillPopScope`. Should be easy

Answer (score 3):

I am not quite sure what you want to achieve, but most of the time when people want to get rid of the back functionality, because they don't wanna enable the user to control the auth mechanism. For example after the users log in, you don't want them to navigate to the Login page by just press on the back button(or swipe back in iOS). A potential solution is, using `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil`.

`Future<T> pushNamedAndRemoveUntil<T extends Object>(BuildContext context, String newRouteName, RoutePredicate predicate)`

> Push the route with the given name onto the navigator that most
>   tightly  encloses the given context, and then remove all the previous
>   routes until  the `predicate` returns true.

Example code:
`pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/home', ModalRoute.withName('/home'));`

**Note: use this method to some certain extent, because you might mess up your navigation history.**

Comment: That doesn't quite take care of all situations... It was also navigating back occasionally even with a left side panel/drawer swipe to open gesture