# Flutter web: how to fix white page on swipe back in IOS when app is installed to home screen

Tags: ios, flutter, safari, flutter-web

If I swipe back from a very first page of any flutter app installed to home screen from Safari I receive a blank page:

[the swiping process picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8Arn.jpg)

It goes back automatically to the first page in three seconds and doesn't appear anymore until the app is reloaded. I used a sample flutter app without any changes to reproduce this behavior.

What I've tried to fix this:

1. `WillPopScope` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161644/flutter-disable-swipe-to-navigate-back-in-ios-and-android), but it's only useful in Safari tab and doesn't have any effect on a home screen app. I tried to wrap `Scaffold` of a home widget and the whole app just to check.
2. Any tricks with `Navigator` weren't helpful. If I try to pop anything from a home page like this:

```
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
        new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()));
```

, i (obviously) receive an error: `Navigator has no active routes to replace.`

3. I also tried to use the `fullscreenDialog: true` parameter in `MaterialPageRoute` when navigated to the next page but the blank page on swipe back remains.

How to get rid of this behavior properly?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem and I believe this has not been solved yet. Looks to be tracked by this (and related) issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76478

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31454211)